# hardcoding CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

https://github.com/ryanatwork/sign-in-with-linkedin

This example rails application that lets a user log in with LinkedIn requires that the "rails server" command in the terminal be prefaced by 'CONSUMER_KEY=[consumer key] CONSUMER_SECRET=[consumer secret]' so that the whole command  looks like:

CONSUMER_KEY=[consumer key] CONSUMER_SECRET=[consumer secret] rails server

The linkedin login obviously won't work with a consumer key/secret, but I'm having trouble hardcoding my consumer key/secret into the app so that I can deploy to Heroku successfully, but am not having any luck. I've tried in several different config and controller files without any luck. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy to Heroku you need to have these variables set using the [`heroku config`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) command:

```
heroku config:add CONSUMER_KEY=[consumer key]
```

If you use [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to start your server (as Heroku does at their end) then you can have these variables [loaded from a local file](http://blog.akash.im/per-project-environment-variables-with-forema) which never gets committed into your source control (you *don't* want these secret details in your source control)

Answer (score 1):

Don't hardcode to heroku. You can use environment variables in Heroku to set CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET.

Here are the docs from Heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars